# Creating Azure storage table on asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage

I'm following this blog post to create an azure storage table:
http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2008/10/28/walkthrough-simple-table-storage.aspx

It works fine on an asp.net webform web_role.

I've re-created the same project using asp.net mvc as the web role, and it's always failing on application start. this line:

```
StorageAccountInfo account = StorageAccountInfo.GetDefaultTableStorageAccountFromConfiguration();
```

seem to always fail getting the account shared key.

If I move the line from global asax application start to default.aspx, it works perfectly fine.

Is there any difference in initializing a storage table in azure asp.net mvc compared to webform?

Why can't I get the azure appsettings on application start?

This is the error call stack from event viewer

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: No account key specified! 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:5100/do.__rd_runtime_init__?shutdownEvent=1B671B93FD-4153-4834-9D5D-595EFC6C19EE1D 
    Request path: /do.__rd_runtime_init__ 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: *****

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 6 
    Thread account name: *****
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetPipelineApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the "remarks" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicehosting.serviceruntime.rolemanager.aspx:

> The Windows Azure fabric runs IIS 7.0
>   in integrated mode. In integrated
>   mode, the Application_Start event does
>   not support access to the request
>   context or to the members of the
>   RoleManager class provided by the
>   Windows Azure SDK runtime API. If you
>   are writing an ASP.NET application
>   that accesses the request context or
>   calls methods of the RoleManager class
>   from the Application_Start event, you
>   should modify it to initialize in the
>   Application_BeginRequest event
>   instead.
>
> For an example that shows how to use
>   the Application_BeginRequest event,
>   see the PersonalWebSite Sample that
>   ships with the Windows Azure SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
StorageAccountInfo account = StorageAccountInfo.GetDefaultTableStorageAccountFromConfiguration();
```

Usually the account information is given in the Web.conf file.

```
<add key="TableStorageEndpoint" value="http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1" />
<add key="AccountName" value="devstoreaccount1" />
<add key="AccountSharedKey" value="YOUR ACCOUNT KEY PROVIDED BY AZURE"/>
```